# XSLT - Use Variable to Store Attributes to Match on in Templates

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have two templates matching the same attributes, both with different modes (shown below).  Is there a way that I can avoid writing the attributes twice, one for each template, and instead store those attributes in say a variable?  So instead of the match statements below I would have a match like **match=$styleAttributes**, and **styleAttributes** would be set to all the attributes.  This would be using version 2.0 (Saxon 9.1.0.7).  Thanks.

```
<xsl:template match="@width|@height|@visible|@vAlign|@hAlign|@zOrder|@hOffset|@vOffset|@color|@fontSize" mode="styles">
    <!-- Do something -->
</xsl:template> 

<!-- Do nothing -->     
<xsl:template match="@width|@height|@visible|@vAlign|@hAlign|@zOrder|@hOffset|@vOffset|@color|@fontSize" mode="common" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can match on everything with `"@*"` and then within the template check the `local-name()` against a global variable, and then call another template with a different `@mode=` depending on pass-fail.

SO is an awesome resource, but for pure XSLT questions, nothing beats the xsl-list run by Mulberry Technologies. It is well-represented by vendors and users of XSLT products, as well as by the members of the W3C committees responsible for the specs.

Comment: The only problem here is that doing so might affect optimizations done by XSLT processor.

Answer (score 1):

**Even in [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20) a [match pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#patterns) can only contain a veriable reference as part of a predicate or as part of the argument (expression) for the [key()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-key) or [id()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-id) functions.
This determines the negative answer to the direct question.**

However, if we need to avoid repeating the same match pattern in two templates that only differ by mode, then one way to achieve this is to use only a single template with no mode and to pass (what used to be) the mode as a parameter to the template.

*Here is a small example*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 >
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=
    "@width|@height|@visible|@vAlign|@hAlign|@zOrder|@hOffset|@vOffset|@color|@fontSize">
      <xsl:param name="procMode" as="xs:string" select="'common'"/>

     <xsl:sequence select=
      "if($procMode = 'common')
        then
          'Hello from the Common Processor'
        else
          'Hello from the Styles Processor'
      "
      />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<div width="50"/>
```

**the wanted result is produced:**

Hello from the Common Processor